# How do I download a csv using python from a webpage where there is a download button?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, download

I am trying to write a python function that downloads/gets a csv from this webpage once a month https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/references/country-data-codes/

However I can only download the csv by clicking the "Download Data" button.

I tried to use the inspect tool on the button to find the function associated with it but was unable to locate it. Using inspect on the Download Data button in general does not seem to give any information I can use.

What's the best way I can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the CSV download that happens when you click the button, it's getting the data from a blob (e.g. my download was reportedly from `blob:https://www.cia.gov/85276989-91b3-4b6d-bcd6-803849afbb1c`). Blobs make it hard to find the real source of the data it's giving out.

Looking at the page source, they load the table in HTML, not from JavaScript, so you're probably better off using the `beautifulsoup` package to extract data directly from the table element (and its rows) and transform that into a CSV using Python rather than chase down the elusive blob's source.

Answer (score 1):

When we are clicking on download option they are collecting all the data displayed and converting it into CSV file and providing the data. There is no link to download direct CSV file.

We can get this data into our code and we can write the data to CSV file in 2 ways.

1. From JSON data: We are getting all the details they are showing in the table from this [request](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/page-data/references/country-data-codes/page-data.json) so if we are making this request we can get the data in JSON format so we can write this into CSV file and use.
2. From HTML data: The data they are displaying is also present in this HTML [request](https://www.cia.gov/the-world-factbook/references/country-data-codes/) so we can make this request and parse it, then we can access this data using following XPATH //table[contains(@class,'content-table')]/tbody/tr

So we can follow one of the above method and get the data and write to CSV file.